PCB trace impedances of integrated circuits with high input impedance
There is an ADC front end IC (opamp) at the input of my ADC card and it has high input impedance,
What should I set the differential trace impedance to when drawing the PCB? Does this matter much?


In the layout guidelines of the datasheet, it is recommended to "make sure that both input paths are symmetrical and well-matched for source impedance and capacitance".
Without knowing your design & requirements, it is hard to say what impedance value that is and whether it "would matter much".

Assuming an analog signal (no square waves with energy beyond 20kHz), the feed from whatever you are measuring would need to be a long way to need treatment as a controlled impedance transmission line.

What I mean is, the datasheet does not mention any trace impedance (the application is not high speed, so it is understandable), is it a good practice to keep the differential characteristic impedance at 50 ohms at 1ghz?Otherwise, it will not be a problem if I do not worry about this and use the trace width that suits my mind without making any impedance calculations.

Is the whole system supposed to have a target impedance?


is it a good practice to keep the differential characteristic impedance at 50 ohms at 1ghz?

I'd call this "overengineering". A 50-Ohm pair on a PCB will look like ~0 Ohm at audio frequencies because trace-to-trace (on the same layer) and trace-to-plane capacitances (assuming you'll have a ground plane underneath), and trace inductances will already be so low that they will not come into play. This makes the trace impedance irrelevant at these frequencies.
For any differential signal, the length mismatch should not be so high that one signal arrives before or after the other by a significant amount of time (They would no longer be "differential, though). Here, "significant" depends on the operation frequency. For gigahertz frequencies, even a fraction of a millimetre matters. But for audio frequencies, I can't calculate at the moment but, it should be tens or maybe hundreds of centimetres (or even metres) to cause sampling problems.
So, ...

Does this matter much?

... no, it doesn't.

In a way, it may seem like overthinking, but in a project before me, the ADC front end was designed with fully differential. Additionally, there were passive filters at the input and the input impedance dropped to 25 ohms at a level of around 20khz. In this case, the ADC input was killing the source (the input signal cannot give such a high current). Moreover, the one who made this mistake was an engineer with 10 years of experience. That's why I wanted to suspect every step and make sure what was going on behind it. Thanks for the answer

At 20 kHz, the RF trace impedance is irrelevant, as is balancing the physical length of each trace.
What you do want to do is keep the loop area between the traces as small as possible, to avoid magnetic pickup.
You probably want to keep the capacitance of each to ground low, so you can maintain bandwidth even with high impedance inputs, and keep the capacitance to ground balanced, to avoid unbalancing a differential input.
